# configuration of log4j2.xml

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

I'm using log4j2. I would like to have 3 exits for my logs: console and 2 rolling files: the first for info log (FileRoot) and the second for errors (FileErrors). After running the project both of files are created, logs are displayed on console and FileErrors, but nothing in FileRoot. What's wrong with my configuration? Here is it:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-10level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="FileRoot" fileName="master/logs/app.log" filePattern="master/logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="FileErrors" fileName="master/logs/appErrors.log" filePattern="master/logs/appErrors-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.yyyy" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.yyyy" level ="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileRoot" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.yyyy" level="ERROR" additivity="false">   
            <AppenderRef ref="FileErrors" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"></AppenderRef>
            <AppenderRef ref="FileRoot" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FileErrors"></AppenderRef>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>``
```

And here are dependencies in pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I use

```
 if( LOG.isInfoEnabled() )
    {
        LOG.info( "app starting" );
    }
```

Comment: Does it only do that for messages in a certain package of just all?

Comment: don't you need to mention ThresholdFilter for FileRoot as well?

Comment: I mentioned ThresholdFilter for FileRoot too, but I have the same prb:-( and both of files are in the same folder: logs